# How do I establish the Academic Year, when I only have a string date

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of dates, in string format,  ranging from "01/01/2000" to "31/12/2022".  If I assume the academic year runs from 1st September to 31st August, how can I return the academic year, in the format "2018-19"?

Presently I'm going down the route of converting the string to an integer :-

```
import datetime

def give_academic_year(theDate):
    utc_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(theDate, '%d/%m/%Y')
    a = datetime.datetime.timestamp(utc_time)

    # Now I was going to do some cluncky comparison for each academic year
    if a>946684800 and a<978307200:
        return "2000-01"
    elif a>978307200 and a<1009756800:
        return "2001-02"
    etc.
```

But there is probably a much more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: _Parse_ the day, month, year , not convert to Unix time

Comment: Or, convert "1st September (year)" to a Unix timestamp in code rather than hard code a number, for example

Comment: The `utc_time` object that you create in the first line of your function has `.month` and `.year` attributes.  Those should allow you to get to your desired result pretty straightforwardly.

Comment: if you were just looking at a list of dates on paper, how would you decide it in your head?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do it in the following way just playing with the year and the formats from the datetime function of the same library.

```
from datetime import datetime

def give_academic_year(theDate):
    if theDate.month > 8:
        return '{0}-{1}'.format(theDate.year, int(theDate.strftime('%y'))+1)
    else:
        return '{0}-{1}'.format((theDate.year-1), theDate.strftime('%y'))

# example
theDate = datetime.strptime('01/03/2020', '%d/%m/%Y')
give_academic_year(theDate)
```

then it only remains to apply the function to the list, you can do it with a lambda expression.

regards.

Comment: `(theDate.year+1).strftime('%y')` will give an error, because it's calling `.strftime` on an int, not a datetime.

Comment: Apply the correction pointed out by @slothrop, I appreciate the observation

Answer (score -1):

Oh, @slothrop, that is elegant!  I didn't know about those attributes.

So this seems to do the job for me :-

```
if utc_time.month>8:
   acam_year=str(utc_time.year)+"-"+str((utc_time.year+1)-2000)
else:
   acam_year=str(utc_time.year-1)+"-"+str((utc_time.year)-2000)
return acam
```

Just the ticket - thanks very much.

Comment: Why subtract 2000? Modulo 100 if you want last two numbers

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @OneCricketeer  It seems to me these are two ways of peeling the same banana. Is there any particular advantage of using Modulo 100 over -2000 ?

Comment: Well, assuming Python is still around in 78 years, then yes, there's a difference. But at the same time, your values for each century would be ambiguous

Comment: Ah, right. Ok - point taken. In all practical terms it doesn't really make a difference (and I certainly won't be around in 78 years time, and nor will the service this provides), but it would be more 'correct' to use Modulo 100. And if I wanted to refer to this for another project where it does make a difference, then you're right - a more correct solution should be used. Thanks!